# While dragging an element in a gridContainer, hovered element above the one dragged won't fire on_mouse_entered but those below will

Tags: user-interface, godot4

So I made a small poc project where the goal is to have a draggeable table, allowing the user to reorder things.

I have this weird behavior currently: When dragging UP, the elements above the one that's being dragged will not detect when the mouse enters them, but when dragging DOWN, they will (and the switch will happen)

So my question is: Do you know what could cause this behavior? Is there any way to set a node to be checked last for mouse enter without ordering it at the top of the tree?

link to the poc: https://github.com/pyrovoice/SortableTableGodotPoc.git

sample code:

```
func onLineButtonPressed(child, isPressed: bool):
    if isPressed:
        draggedComponent = child
    else:
        draggedComponent = null

func onMouseEnterElement(enteredElement, isMouseEnter: bool):
    if draggedComponent && isMouseEnter:
        print("Entered " + enteredElement.name)
        grid_container.move_child(draggedComponent, enteredElement.get_index())

func _input(event):
    if event is InputEventMouseMotion && draggedComponent:
        draggedComponent.position.y += (event as InputEventMouseMotion).relative.y
```

picture after dragging up then down:

https://imgur.com/a/E5k20aj